# Complex analysis computing the integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I=$\int_\gamma \operatorname{Im}(z)\mathrm dz$

$\gamma$ is the interval between $\omega_1=0$ and $\omega_2=1+2\mathrm i$

How can I compute the integral above? I have no process about this question. I`m sorry about it.

Comment: There is not really a notion of an interval in the complex numbers. Do you mean the straight line between these two point? What are $I$ and $m$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply the definition: If $D\subseteq\mathbb C$, $\gamma:[a,b]\to D$ is the parametrization of a smooth curve and $f:D\to\mathbb C$, then

$$\int_\gamma f(z)\mathrm dz:=\int_a^b \gamma'(t) f(\gamma(t))\mathrm dt.$$

In your case, $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb C,~\gamma(t)=(1+2\mathrm i)t$ is a suitable parametrization, and $f(z)=\operatorname{Im}z$. Plugging everything in:

$$\int_\gamma\operatorname{Im}z\mathrm dz=\int_0^1(1+2\mathrm i)\operatorname{Im}((1+2\mathrm i)t)\mathrm dt=\int_0^1(1+2\mathrm i)2t\mathrm dt.$$

I think you can do the rest by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and your effort. I only have one question. When we parametrize it how could we find out the interval [0,1] ?

Comment: It's really arbitrary. I could have chosen the parametrization $\gamma:[0,\sqrt5]\to\mathbb C,~\gamma(t)=t\frac{1+2\mathrm i}{\sqrt5}$, or weirder yet, $\gamma:[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\to\mathbb C,~\gamma(t)=(1+2\mathrm i)\sin(t)$. The only important thing is that the parametrization is: a) smooth, b) start and end points are $0$ and $1+2\mathrm i$, and c) The curve stays on the line. But the simplest parametrization of a straight line is linear interpolation between the endpoints, $\gamma(t)=\omega_1+t(\omega_2-\omega_1)$. This will result in $\gamma(0)=\omega_1,~\gamma(1)=\omega_2$.

Comment: Thank you for making it so easier. I understood the whole point now.